# Is it possible to create a custom flashMode in AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, iphone-xs

Today I found out that settings like a custom exposuremode or a fixed lens position in the focus mode, which I set for the AVCaptureDevice in my AVCaptureSession conflicted with the flashMode.on option of the AVCaptureSettings, as it alters the previously specified ISO and exposure duration values etc. .

So my question is: Is it possible to specify a custom flashMode that does not analyze the viewed scene and uses strictly pre-defined settings?

For me it is more valuable to be in control of these settings, even though it might lead to a loss of photo quality.